# micro controller cant able to sense analog value (ADC input) from op amp output

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement

I am trying to sense the current in my motor controller using shunt resistor and an op amp. Opp amp amplifies the voltage drop of the shunt resistor, multi meter shows the output voltage good.

But when i connect that to a  Micro controller, the ADC can't able to sense the voltage.  So i connect the opp amp output to the Scope to see whats happening, since i am driving a motor as load the op amp output is like noise  sin wave (due to parasitic inductance think so).

I uses RC filter to sense the analog value, but even that to not works well.

Used --Micro controller stm32f103,  op amp LM358 and shunt resistor 0.001 ohm.

[image]

[image]

How to reduce the effect of noise in op amp output or how to sense current for motor application. Is the method i am following is correct. Guide me guys friends where i am wrong.

Comment: The op-amp does actually need power rails. Where are they?

Comment: If you suppose the max output from the opamp is about 3 V then the full-scale input current is 75 A.  In other words the circuit can measure a signal from 0 to 75 A.   How much current are you actually trying to measure?  It will probably not measure well if the current is less than 0.75 A.

Comment: We need to know the part number for the op amp, also post a oscilloscope pic of the noise you see.

Comment: @Andyaka supply given to opp amp was  vcc=12v & vee=0v. Or should give -6v to +6v ( virtual gnd concept) ?

Comment: @scorpdaddy For example i consume 2amp load, the output of the op amp is good which is clear in multi meter.  But micro controller's ADC cant able to sense the output, just because the output is noisy. I will post the scope output soon

Comment: @laptop2d Op amp= LM358, i will post the scope output soon.

Comment: @Nihal, your statements are contradictory.  Either the output is good or the output is noisy.  It can't be both.  Posting scope trace on ADC in would help.

Comment: @scorpdaddy , yes your correct the output is not good. What I mean was, the Multimeter show's the opamp output which is constant and various linearly respectivd to current ,but not correct. I will update scope traces.